# Generate a sound of specific frequency

Tags: javascript, audio

I found this library : http://codebase.es/riffwave/ which generate sounds on-the-fly in javascript.

What I want is to have a function which generates a sine wave of a specific frequency.

But the way we use the library is with a lot of math and I wasn't able to make it work.

I tried

```
for(var i=0;i<10000;i++)data.push(127*(Math.sin(2*Math.PI*f*i)));
```

but it didn't work.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var freq = 440;  // Frequency (cycles per second)
var rate = 44100;  // Sample rate (samples per second)
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    var time = i / rate;       
    data[i] = 128 + Math.round(127 * (Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * freq * time)));
}
```

Comment: OMG! It's perfect, thanks a lot! And can you tell me what is the rate?

Comment: The sampling rate determines how many samples per second there are.  The higher the rate, the higher the quality. 44100 Hz is a common rate, so I took a guess that riffwave uses it as the default.

Comment: In fact if you do `alert(wave.header.sampleRate);` you will see it's 8000. But hopefully I had `wave.header.sampleRate=rate;` in my code. (I don't know why I wrote that)